# Assigning a single value to multiple variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me with the syntax for assigning a single integer value to multiple variables in Excel VBA?

Comment: please explain better, what do you mean for multiple variables ? can you show your code ?

Comment: Read this article: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html

Comment: If you need to store (permanently) the same value into multiple variables, then you have badly designed variables to begin with. It would do you good, if you described what you want to achieve instead

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim SingleValue As Integer, alpha As Integer, beta As Integer, gamma As Integer
    SingleValue = 12
    alpha = SingleValue: beta = SingleValue: gamma = SingleValue
End Sub
```